# How to display shipping method customer group wise in Magento?

Tags: magento, paypal

I need to display payment method for wholesaler -> "Cheque/Moneyorder". and retailer -> "paypal".

and shipping method also wholesaler -> free. and retailer -> table rate.

Please help me anyone to work out this.

Answer (score 0):

Better Option you can create the Shopping cart price rule in Admin panel.

Path :

```
Admin => Promotions => Shopping Cart Price Rules => Add New Rule
```

to customize and set the condition for your criteria.

Comment: thanks for reply but what for payment method. that should also select as per customer group

Comment: COD for wholesaler and paypal for retailer, how to accomplish this?

Comment: Rule 1 : Customer Group is Wholesaler to set COD PAYMENY. 2) Custmer Group is retailed to set payment method is Paypal.